# Is there a better way to read locally and write globally? (Design Distributed Systems)

Tags: azure, distributed, azure-table-storage, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

**Scenario**
I need to design a system which should be able to read from local database and perform writes to all its replicas
(currently using Azure Tables).
I would appreciate if someone could share their approach to achieve this.

*Existing design*

Region 1: A node with "computeScore" service running. And a database of all customer data.

Region 2: A node with "computeScore" service running.

ComputeScore Service is called at every successful login of a user. It reads the previous login information of the same user from the database in Region 1 and computes a score. This score is written again to the database in Region 1.

**Issue**
Whenever a customer request is routed to Region 2 (based on the current location of the users, the requests are routed to their nearest physical server), it makes an extra call to Region 1 database to perform the database operations, which obviously results in extra time when compared to customers hitting Region 1.

One way to do it is to maintain a copy of the database at both the regions, but the challenge here would be consistency (writing back the score that is computed) and how do you achieve this.

Looking for a solution to avoid the extra latency for customers directed to Region 2.

Comment: There are databases that can automatically replicate cross-data-center (e.g. Cassandra).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I learnt that there is no support as such in azure-table-storage. So looking for better ideas.